# RecyclerView with view pager

Tags: android, layout, android-recyclerview

I have a working piece of code which works when built on other machines but if i build using my machine, the adapter does not show up. No elements of the adapter are populated.

I have RecyclerView inside a ViewPager.

I have updated SDK and Android Studio as well.

LOGS

```
05-30 16:13:15.637 17918-17918/ E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null

05-30 16:13:15.877 17918-17922/ D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 630K, 17% free 9656K/11592K, paused 12ms+4ms, total 39ms
05-30 16:13:15.887 17918-17918/ I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>, referenced from method android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$LayoutParams.<init>
05-30 16:13:15.887 17918-17918/ W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve direct method 19614: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;.<init> (Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;)V
05-30 16:13:15.887 17918-17918/ D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x0000
05-30 16:13:15.897 17918-17918/ I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>, referenced from method android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$LayoutParams.<init>
05-30 16:13:15.897 17918-17918/ W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve direct method 19614: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;.<init> (Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;)V
05-30 16:13:15.897 17918-17918/ D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x0000
```

Please help

Comment: hmm can't say anything without any logcat or piece of code, you getting the data from server?

Comment: yes, didnt shared code as it works when built from different machine.

Comment: shared the logs now, please check

Comment: I think your `build.gradle` is missing  design dependency , try compiling this `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'` in your `build.gradle`

Comment: it worked!!!! Thanks man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `build.gradle` is missing design dependency,

try compiling this dependency

```
com.android.support:design:23.4.0
```

in your build.gradle